# Windows - Split 4.0 audio to 2 stereo devices

Tags: windows, audio

I would like to play movies in 4.0 with 2 stereo systems. So I try to route FrontLeft and FrontRight channels to a first stereo USB DAC and RearLeft and RearRight to an other stereo USB DAC.

I used [Voicemeeter](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/) or [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) but I can't choose wich channel to route to a device so I end up with FrontLeft and FrontRight on both devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not planned for that, but there is a workaround with Voicemeeter Banana version (REBOOT after de-installation / REBOOT after de-installztion). Then you will have at least 2 independent BUS to physical output (A1 & A2)...

for the Front, it is not a problem since it will be automatically routed to BUS (A1 for example) Left & Right. But for rear left and right, you can use the COMPOSITE MODE on second Bus (A2 for example) and define the patch of this COMPOSITE MODE in Voicemeeter System Settings Dialog Box. Then you will be able to select the channel #5 of the virtual input as LEFT (COMPOSITE channel #1) and channel #6 of the virtual input as RIGHT (COMPOSITE channel #2)...